# Какой фреймворк выбрать для изучения?

Tags: php, framework

framework обучение php

Comment: Django или ROR

Comment: Возможно, подскажите какие-либо книги, видео, желательно на русском языке. Заранее благодарен, всем кто откликнется помочь в моем не легком начинании! Объясните, чем Django или Ruby on Rails лучше фреймворков для PHP?

Comment: Тем что язык лучше

Comment: @eprivalov1, зачем в ответе дублировать комментарий? Лучше задайте это отдельным вопросом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

начните с codeigniter, самый простой из MVC. Далее можно попробовать CakePHP или Kohana. После - Yii и Zend. Но начинать советую с Codeigniter. Далее сами поймете что вам надо.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется Kohana идеальна как для начального обучения так и более профессиональной деятельности. [Документация хорошая](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api). Книг не встречал. [Русскоязычное сообщество](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/categories/russkoyazychnoe-soobschestvo).